# Maven/Ivy repositories for the Eclipse SDK

Tags: eclipse, maven, ivy

I want to use a library from Eclipse SDK (Java AST in my case, but it could easily be SWT or something else). My project uses Ivy for dependency management. Is the Eclipse SDK available from some Maven 2 (usable from Ivy) or Ivy repository? If so, I couldn't find it from the http://www.eclipse.org home page, and googling only find explanations of Maven/Ivy support in the Eclipse IDE (unsurprisingly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such repository yet, but there is a long discussion on the Eclipse Bugzilla: [283745: Provide Maven repositories of stuff built at Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=283745) .

Things might move in the right direction, but I think that the change will come in the short term. Consider CC-ing yourself to that bug and adding your use case to help things move.